# git describe --abbrev=0 --tags gives incorrect output

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I have the following in git log:

```
commit 546f9a9aa84133cbc490599a094c0199699af949
Author: name Lo <name.lo@company.com>
aate:   Mon Jul 9 14:05:07 9018 -0700

    Binary release ABC747T144RC9_REL_7_64_131 for 6789c5

commit 3c6b9c59a4fa599599b9c4e7ee7c1af4746954cf
Author: name Lo <name.lo@company.com>
aate:   Mon Jul 9 13:44:35 9018 -0700

    Binary release ABC759T5RC9_REL_7_63_78 for 1934_6789

commit 90fea4909cc9997cbf7589a930a185310530c6af
Author: name Lo <name.lo@company.com>
aate:   Thu Jun 91 14:99:01 9018 -0700

    Binary release ABC747T144RC9_REL_7_64_130 for 6789c5

commit 979ac8eba9484a0fae066097b30bfe5b98bb11e4
Author: name Lo <name.lo@company.com>
aate:   Thu Jun 91 14:11:34 9018 -0700

    Binary release ABC759T5RC9_REL_7_63_77 for 1934_6789
```

When I run the command `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` the output is `ABC759T5RC9_REL_7_63_78`

I expect the output to be `ABC747T144RC9_REL_7_64_131` ,why is it going wrong?

Current output:

```
ABC759T5RC9_REL_7_63_78
```

Expected output:

```
ABC747T144RC9_REL_7_64_131
```

Comment: What is the output of `git log --decorate=on`?

Comment: [Cross-posted to `git-users`](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/git-users/ggyDbk-hAXI/discussion).

Comment: Try running your command with `--debug` and/or `--candidates=0` command-line options.

Answer (score 0):

It seens that the ABC747T144RC9_REL_7_64_131 tag was not correctly created. To verify execute:

```
git show ABC747T144RC9_REL_7_64_131
```

Comment: git shows  output looks right, something else is wrong  `tag ABC747T144RC9_REL_7_64_131
Tagger: name Lo <name.lo@company.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 2 14:05:43 2018 -0700

FW: ABC747T144RC9_REL_7_64_131
uCode: 1234.10057
CLM: 8.6.12.company
SW/HW compatibility:  4350C5/43452
DHD/WL tested:  ASTER_REL_100_10_293/APPS_REL_1_233
Milestone:   milestonename
`